# Extract text before two underscores with regex

Tags: python, regex

I feel I am not far from a solution but I still struggle to extract some text from variables with Regex. The conditions are:

- The text can only contain upper case characters or integers
- The text can contain underscores BUT not two consecutive ones

Examples:

```
test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST_13DAHA bfd     -->   TEST_TEST_1_TEST_13DAHA
test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST__13DAHA bfd    -->   TEST_TEST_1_TEST
test__TEST_TEST                      -->   TEST_TEST
test_TEST__DHJF                      -->   TEST
test_TEST__Ddsa                      -->   TEST
test__TEST                           -->   TEST
```

So far, I got

`_([0-9A-Z_]+)` works for the first one but not the second
`_([0-9A-Z_]+)(?:__.*)+` works for the second one but not the first

Comment: Interesting, is `test_TEST bfd` a valid test case? What is expected?

Comment: Please try the https://ideone.com/Z60lxz solution.

Comment: Explain the logic behind `test_TEST__DHJF` and why `TEST` is an expected match but not `DHJF`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, interesting but it returns too many groups.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the logic is that I don't want string after the two underscores if some string (i.e. uppercase and numbers) already matched before

Comment: No, it returns `['TEST']` for `test_TEST bfd`, `['TEST_TEST_1_TEST_13DAHA']` for `test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST_13DAHA` and `['TEST_TEST_1_TEST']` for `test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST__13DAHA bfd`. Just the matches. Looks like it does not return the expected results for `test__TEST_TEST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you don't want the string after the two underscores if some string already matched before, i.e. you may consume and omit all the letters/digits after double or more underscores after capturing the expected pattern:

```
_([0-9A-Z]+(?:_[0-9A-Z]+)*)(?:__[0-9A-Z_]+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yzC9L4/1). The `(?:__[0-9A-Z_]+)?` part "excludes" trying to match the text that comes right after your match.

You need to get Group 1 values rather than the whole match values, hence `re.findall` suits best here, especially if you expect multiple matches. If you expect a single match per string, use `re.search`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/K6vdET):

```py
import re
cases = ["test_TEST bfd",
    "test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST_13DAHA bfd",
    "test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST__13DAHA bfd",
    "test__TEST_TEST",
    "test_TEST__DHJF",
    "test_TEST__Ddsa"
]
pattern = re.compile(r'_([0-9A-Z]+(?:_[0-9A-Z]+)*)(?:__[0-9A-Z_]+)?')
for case in cases:
    matches = pattern.findall(case)
    print(matches)
```

[With `re.search`](https://ideone.com/T5Zo1j):

```py
for case in cases:
    match = pattern.search(case)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
TEST
TEST_TEST_1_TEST_13DAHA
TEST_TEST_1_TEST
TEST_TEST
TEST
TEST
```

Comment: Really nice, I got the general idea but was far from fetch. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
[A-Z0-9]+(?=_)(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)*
```

Sample script:

```py
inp = ["test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST_13DAHA bfd", "test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST__13DAHA bfd", "test__TEST_TEST", "test_TEST__DHJF"]
for i in inp:
    matches = re.findall(r'[A-Z0-9]+(?=_)(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)*', i)
    print(i + " => " + matches[0])
```

This prints:

```
test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST_13DAHA bfd => TEST_TEST_1_TEST_13DAHA
test_TEST_TEST_1_TEST__13DAHA bfd => TEST_TEST_1_TEST
test__TEST_TEST => TEST_TEST
test_TEST__DHJF => TEST
```

Comment: Fails on leading and trailing underscores

Comment: @ChrisMaurer What makes you think that the OP wants to catch leading or trailing underscores?  I see no evidence of this.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you. Indeed, leading and tailing underscores are out of scope

Comment: Would have been nice to have said so...

Comment: However, on my dataset, I forgot other corner cases, my bad. I added them in the examples

Comment: @GuillaumeA I have updated my answer such that it now passes all your test cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and if add the last example ? (sorry for bothering you)